# Jmeter Throwing Exception for class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger

Tags: java, exception, jmeter, jmx

My Jmeter used to work just fine and it stopped working suddenly for me and my co-workers. After we import the JMX and run the tests, it returns this:

> Request: nil
>   Response: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogKitLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:874)
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)

How to fix this?

Comment: You've got to be more specific: what's Java version, JMeter version, does the jmx use any plug-ins; did it start happening after upgrade

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibles explanations:

- Your installation has to been corrupted as somes jars are not being found. So reinstall it to see if it works
- You are using a 3rd party plugin (Plugins Manager for example), depending on the version you're using there are known bugs that can lead to this situation. Try from a clean JMeter installation first, if it works, install then plugin manager last version and try. Report a bug to them if it's the root cause.